# Dreamweaver drop down menu

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, adobe, dreamweaver

i have a menu bar in which i have tags women, men, designer etc etc.. i want such that if my mouse cursor moves onto women or it moves onto men, then a drop down appears.. how to do this using Adobe Dreamweaver cs3..

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want some sort of JavaScript or CSS mouseover menu. This is pretty common around the web. If you Google for "JavaScript dropdown menu" you'll probably find something useful.

As far as I know, you'll have to code it by hand. I don't think Dreamweaver has the capability built-in to create flexible JavaScript dropdown menus.